# Why isn't this bootstrap carousel working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[IMAGE IS WHAT I SEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMN3e.jpg)
Trying to get this carousel working.
I've tried CSS and and other ideas, but it isn't working.

> ERROR: The photos are shown one after the other and are not in
> "carousel" style. It looks like I just slapped the pictures onto the
> code, there's no carousel at all.

Here's my code:

```
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="couple-walking-dog-in-front-of-well_orig.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="th.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="victory-girl_orig.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Look in the console, what errors do you get?

Comment: There are no error messages, it runs fine

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your class names. `item` should be `carousel-item`, `left carousel control` should be `carousel-control-prev` and a few more.

Fixing those should give you the desired result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed on a class name.
Your code

```
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
```

It looks like the last class should be: "*carousel-item active*" instead of just: "*item active*"

Comment: I changed it and it's still not working. Still looks like image I posted above. I'll leave it in though because I'm pretty sure I did miss that class name lol.